# cannot fetch data from Firebase database

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, zip

I have done this, but it says to me class bool has no instance methood [] reciver null tried
calling []ok

```
class Test7 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Test7State createState() => _Test7State();
}

class _Test7State extends State<Test7> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body:  SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Flexible(
          child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            query: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(currentUser.uid), // when i remove child(currentUser.uid)it is work !
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,Animation<double> animation,  int index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                ),
                title: Text(snapshot.value["ok"]),
              );
            },),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and I have this in Firebase database real time

```
    NUuhYzfVS9YPYDIox3X6ozhzFiT2
activity: true
ok: "ok"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `FirebaseAnimatedList` shows the list of child nodes under the path in the database that you specify in `query`. If you specify the UID in that path, you end up with these two child nodes:

```
activity: true
ok: "ok"
```

So your `itemBuilder` gets called twice: once for `activity: true` and once for `ok: "ok"`. When you then call `snapshot.value["ok"]` on that `snapshot`, there is no such **child** property anymore.

Bottom line: a `FirebaseAnimatedList` only makes sense if you're showing a list of users. When you're showing a specific user, you can't show it in a `FirebaseAnimatedList`, and you'll typically want to show it in a `Text` widget, using (for example) a `FutureBuilder`:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(currentUser.uid).get(),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Something went wrong");
    }

    if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
      return Text("Document does not exist");
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      return Text(snapshot.data.value["ok"]);
    }

    return Text("loading");
  },
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this awesome answer , can i use Database into stream.builder instead future too ?

Comment: i just forgot to mark the answer , sorry 
i tried this 
stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("uid).snapshot(), 
but it gives error , if you give me small example of how to make it into stream instead future in the last answer will be thankful , i just new in Firebase , i know you answered of how to use stream , but with example  i can understand more

Comment: There is no `snapshot` method, but there are `on...` properties that expose `Stream`s, such as `onValue`. See https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query-class.html and probably some of these: https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+firebase+onvalue or even https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+firebase+onvalue+streambuilder

Comment: thanks a lot Mr.puf , i really appreciate that